# Get a String value from its hashCode

Tags: java, string, hashcode

Is there an easy way to get the value of a string using its hashcode? Let me explain:

I have a string variable which has value `Hello Guys`. It is saved here: `String@dye63g`. Now, I want to get the string value `Hello Guys` from `String@dye63g`.

Comment: `String@dye63g` is not something any built-in java method produces. As a general point of principle, reversing a hash is by definition impossible, but I'm not so sure that's a hash. How did you get this string?

Comment: You'll need to build a lookup table that you can use to reverse the hash function. You cannot reverse a hash function without it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). May I ask what you are trying to build?

Comment: Seems like the only way to get `String@dye63g` from the `String` class is to have the string value `"String@dye63g"`

Comment: It looks like the standard impl of `toString`, i.e.: `System.out.println(new Object());` prints `java.lang.Object@53e25b76`, however, [A] the 'hash' part is 8 symbols long and not 6, and [B] these symbols are 0-9a-f. It cannot include a `y` or a `g`. It feels like OP saw something like this and just made up what they remembered. Failing to register that they're 8 long and only contain 0-9a-f, and that `j.l.String` has its own toString impl and would thus never print this.

Comment: You are right @rzwitserloot. Just an example for what I remember

Comment: @lorisleitner can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments on this question, your question is REALLY asking:

For an object whose class does **not** override the default `toString()` from `java.lang.Object` itself, can I derive the value again?

The answer is a resounding no. It's **NOT A HASH**. It's the fully qualified class name, an `@` symbol, then in hexdigits (so 0-9a-f, not y and g like in your example), the value returned by `System.identityHashCode(obj)`.

This code has no relationship at all with the value of it and isn't the hashCode of that object. It's, usually, its memory address or some modification of that principle.

You can trivially test this:

```java
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode("Hey, there!"));
  }
}
```

Run that a few times. The same value *might* come out (it depends on your system and VM impl), but now run the same code on a different VM, or on a different computer, or reboot and run it again. Different values come out. That should make it rather obvious that you can't.

A second issue is the pigeonhole principle. That hash value is always exactly 32 bits long (why? Well, `System.identityHashCode` returns an `int` and those only have 32 bits. Each letter (0-9a-f) represents 4 bytes, hence why that thing after the `@` is always 8 characters long: each character is 4 bits, 8*4 = 32.

You can test that too. Copy/paste the collected works of Shakespear into a single gigantic string, and now invoke `identityHashCode` on that - it's still just a short number.

There are 4 billion different numbers that an `int` can represent and that's it. However, there are more than 4 billion strings imaginable (there are an infinite amount of them, in fact). Hence, there must exist an infinite amount of different strings that all so happen to hash to, say, 1234abcd. Thus, given the hash 1234abcd, it is impossible to say which string produced it - after all, an infinite amount of strings exist that hash to that value. And that's presuming the hashing is 'constant' (same string results in the same hash, e.g. what string's own `.hashCode()` method does). `System.identityHashCode` isn't even that and in fact has no relationship at all to the actual value. The number you get depends on, effectively, the memory load of the system when you boot the JVM, more or less.